# Backup and Migrate Drupal module causes fatal error

Tags: drupal

Drupal 7, Backup and Migrate Module

When I click "Backup now" button in Backup and Migrate Drupal module Configuration I get such an error:

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required
>   '/home/content/27/11820827/html/modules/system/system.mail.inc'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in
>   /home/content/27/11820827/html/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 3119

Ones the site was on another hosting everything was ok that days. Then I migrated to another hosting. For first 2s day there were no errors but they started to appear today morning. How to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they may have had something set up on the server like a redirect.

This error is saying that it can't find the route to the mail system which drupal uses so it is failing.

I wouldn't mind betting the old server was using an older version of PHP was it?  Looks like you're using php 5.3 on the new one.

It could have been an issue all along, but did not show until you did something that caused it to try to generate an email.  Try using backup and migrate without sending an email on completion and it will probably work as an interim workaround since it will not use the mail method.